# Java mail client can't reach SMTP server from Docker container

Tags: spring, docker, jakarta-mail

I have created simple Java application which sends emails. It's working properly when I running it from my IDE, but when running it inside a Docker container it can't reach the remote SMTP server. I'm using

```
docker run -d -p 25:25 [image]:[tag]
```

to expose port 25 when starting the container. Does anyone has an idea why the mail client can't connect?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the point of the port mapping. This is to allow the host to bind the specified port on the given network interface to the port in the container. In your case you are trying to connect to port 25 i presume on another remote host.

If the app works when run in the IDE I'd assume either an issue resolving the SMTP server or a problem with the address on which the SMTP server is listening.

Are you running the SMTP server locally or connecting to one that is resolvable via public DNS? If you use `docker exec` to enter the running container can you telnet to the SMTP server?

Comment: I’am using DNS “smtp.gmail.com”, is this means that it fails to resolve DNS? Do i have to configure docker container somehow?

Comment: I don't think you ought to need to do anything special to allow this. I'm at a bit of a loss to explain why that would not work from within the container unless there is some type of firewall blocking the container from connecting outbound on port 25 to `smtp.gmail.com`. Do you have any more details about the problem connecting, e.g. a stacktrace?